# Rcpp , search a value in a file

Tags: c++, rcpp

My Problem :
I want to search a value in a txt file, than run some mathematical Operators over it . is it possible that i search the value like in c++ with Input ( cin >> ..)
Here is my Code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>

//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]



using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]

vector<string> split(string str, char delimiter) {
vector<string> internal;
stringstream ss(str);
string tok;
while (getline(ss, tok, delimiter)) {
    internal.push_back(tok);
}
return internal;
}


//[[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector to_string(SEXP t)
{
return CharacterVector(t);
}


//[[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]


//[[Rcpp::export]]
List read(string filename, string arg)

{


    ifstream file(filename.c_str());

    string search= Rcpp::as<string>(arg);
    // for example   string search="usa";

    string line;
    vector<vector<string>> table;
    while (file.good()) {
        getline(file, line);
        if (!file.fail()) {
            table.push_back(split(line, ','));
        }
    }
    vector<vector<string>> searchResults;

    for (vector<string> line : table) {
        for (string column : line) {
            if (column == suchen) {
                searchResults.push_back(line);
            }
        }
    }


    //calc average
    int length = searchResults.size();
    vector<string> result;
    double secondRow=0;
    double thirdRow =0;
    for (vector<string> line : searchResults) {
        secondRow += atoi(line.at(1).c_str());
        thirdRow += atoi(line.at(2).c_str());
    }






    result.insert(result.begin(), search);
    result.insert(result.end(),to_string(secondRow/length));
    result.insert(result.end(),to_string(thirdRow/length));





    for (string i : result) {
        cout << i ;
    }


    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("search") = search,
        Rcpp::Named("total") =secondRow/length,
        Rcpp::Named("average")= thirdRow/length);

    }
```

And this is my Error ->

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG        -I"C:/Users/xy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"       -I"c:/Users/Yesim/Desktop/julivierrcpp"           -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"  -std=c++14   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2     -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::List read(std::string, std::string)':
main.cpp:48:39: error: no matching function for call to 'as(std::string&)'
string suchen = Rcpp::as<string>(arg);
                                   ^
   main.cpp:48:39: note: candidate is:
   In file included from C:/Users/Yesim/Documents/R/win-                          library/3.4/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:160:0,
             from C:/Users/Yesim/Documents/R/win-                             library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,                  from main.cpp:8:
 C:/Users/xy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:143:29:      note: template<class T> T Rcpp::as(SEXP)
   template <typename T> T as(SEXP x) {
                         ^
  C:/Users/xy/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/as.h:143:29:   note:        template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    main.cpp:48:39: note:   cannot convert 'arg' (type 'std::string {aka             std::basic_string<char>}') to type 'SEXP'
       string search= Rcpp::as<string>(arg);
                                   ^
    make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rcpp should already be able to handle `std::string`s so remove `Rcpp::as<string>` altogether